# How to set a property on MouseEnter event inside a data template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would like to set a CLR property in the `DataContext` when a `MouseEnter` event occurs on a `StackPanel`. However the `StackPanel` is defined inside `DataTemplate` of an `ItemsControl` which is defined inside a Control Template for a custom control inside the `Generic.xaml`.

Example Logic:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type pie:PieChartControl}">

            <Grid>
                    <ItemsControl
                        ItemsSource="{Binding slices, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <Grid>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel.Triggers>

                                            // Need help here...
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                                <Setter Property="MyProp" Value="myVal"/>
                                            </EventTrigger>

                                        </StackPanel.Triggers>

                                        <Rectangle ... />

                                        <TextBlock ... />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

            </Grid>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**EDIT :** Looking for a XAML only solution. Can be easily done with code-behind!

Comment: instead of setting the event trigger in the itemscontrol.itemtemplate try setting it in the control template for the datatemplate

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IsMouseOver Property as a Style Trigger:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="MyProp" Value="myVal" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers/>
```

Or if you want to do something more complicated you could handle that in code behind

```
    <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="YourCodeBehindMethodHere"/>
```

Comment: Dont think it works. It complains that the property name MyProp is not defined for StackPanel.

Comment: You have to use the name of the property you want to change. I took "MyProp" from your example - it doesn't exist

Comment: Ofcourse, that is what I meant ;) When you do a Trigger, you can only do it wit WPF dependency properties and not CLR properties. Hence the error, property name not found. Anyways, I have now used dirty code-behind event handling to accomplish it. Dont like it but cant seem to find any other way!